# Node.js - How do I use modules from another project without copying code?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, build-process

To be completely specific:

1. I am writing a Node.js app that is intended to be a websocket bot for Slack.
2. A [Node project](https://github.com/slackhq/node-slack-client) exists that abstracts the majority of the Slack API. (It is NOT an npm module.)
3. I'm not overly familiar with grunt, etc. but I can get the dependencies to install and utilize all this code by placing my own mybot.js in the root folder of this git clone and running `node mybot.js` with mybot.js being based on the files in the example folder.
4. Committing to my own repository, I don't want to commit any of the aforementioned project code -- it's not mine!  I do, however, want it as a dependency.  Unfortunately, this code by Slack is *not* an npm module that makes it easy to do.  The project has a /bin folder and a /src folder full of coffee script, etc. that grunt builds to .js files.
5. The Slack project code has its own dependencies.  In my way of thinking, those are sub-dependencies for me, or cascading dependencies.  My project only depends on whatever the Slack project depends on.
6. I would like to be able to update my project with updates (manually, or via build) from the git repo of the Slack project as needed.

It seems there must be a way for me to include this project as a dependency, and once built, properly reference it's bin and src folder objects (bin/slack, src/message, client, channel, user, etc.) without committing it to my own repository. Especially great if it could be in a subfolder separate from my own model definitions.  In a way, this seems no different to me than including jQuery in my website layout via a CDN.  I'm only asking for the jQuery project and depending on my link flavor, I can get a specific version or the latest version, etc.

Comment: npm link would work locally

Comment: Why not just put it in a common directory that both projects can reference by specifying the proper path?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/slack-client

Comment: @Ben You know...for some reason I focused on the git repo, instead of that link, with a clearly installable module!  I had thought the slack-client npm was actually just Slack's API via webhooks, not the websocket style I was looking for.  Thanks for getting me in the right direction with blatant clarity.

Comment: @Kevin B:   I spent quite a bit of time trying npm link...and maybe what I stumbled on with actually installing what Ben suggested might have worked had I done it in the correct order.  The require command wasn't being utilized correctly.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out the comment by Ben pointing me to the npmjs.com slack-client npm module was the help I really needed.  I just didn't really know how to ask the right question, I think.

And while I hate to look a gift horse in the mouth, a little more than a link, Ben, would've saved me another three hours, probably.  Perhaps:  "It *is* an npm module, not just a project from github."   But thank you, even if it took me a while to decipher what you were saying.